# function to search for a string in two separate files and print only the matching lines using python3

Tags: python

I have two files eg.
file1 contains the following as a example:

```
[Mon Aug 30 15:32:47.614 2021] <updateMsg> (RDM_UPD_EVENT_TYPE_QUOTE)" seqNum="41648" dataSize="119">
[Mon Aug 30 15:32:47.721 2021] <updateMsg> (RDM_UPD_EVENT_TYPE_QUOTE)" seqNum="41760" dataSize="119">
[Mon Aug 30 15:32:47.722 2021] <updateMsg (RDM_UPD_EVENT_TYPE_QUOTE)" seqNum="41856" dataSize="119">
[Mon Aug 30 15:32:47.895 2021] <updateMsg (RDM_UPD_EVENT_TYPE_QUOTE)" seqNum="41952" dataSize="119">
```

file2 contains the following as a example:

```
[Mon Aug 30 15:32:47.789 2021] <updateMsg> (RDM_UPD_EVENT_TYPE_QUOTE)" seqNum="41648" dataSize="119">
[Mon Aug 30 15:32:47.924 2021] <updateMsg> (RDM_UPD_EVENT_TYPE_QUOTE)" seqNum="41760" dataSize="119">
```

I'm trying to search both files and print only the lines that have matching `seqNum`.

I've have a method that I pass the details too, as below but its not showing the details as expected

```
def get_update_time(seqNu, file1, file2):
    with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
         for x, y in zip(f1, f2):
             if seqNu in x and seqNu in Y:
                 nline1 = x.split("updateMsg")[0] # I just get it down to the time that i require
                 nline2 = y.split("updateMsg")[0] # I just get it down to the time that i require
                 print(nline1, nline2)
```

Note I've also tried the x and y in different "if statements" but still don't get the required results.

Comment: Your code will only find matches if they're in the same numbered line in the files, e.g. file 1 line 1 matches file 2 line 1, file 1 line 2 matches file 2 line 2, etc.

Comment: i would like to print both lines from each file

Comment: Your example shows the `seqNum` to be sorted, is that guaranteed? How large are these files, do they fit in memory?

Comment: "still don't get the required results" unfortunately doesn't tell us what results you *are* actually getting and how they differ from your desired output. - Also, on a side note, if you don't need any other functionality than just searching and printing matching lines in text files, you could use built-in OS tools like `grep` in Unix or `findstr` in Windows.

Comment: No the seqNu are not sorted, but one file has more seqNu than the other and if different orders.

Comment: also the file should fit in memory, as is, but that would be just for this particular example.

Answer (score 0):

Turn one of the files into a dictionary keyed by `seqNum`. Then read the other file and check for a match.

```
import re

with open(file1) as f1:
    log_dict = {re.search(r'seqNum="(\d+)"', line).group(1): line for line in f1}

with open(file2) as f2:
    for line in f2:
        seq = re.search(r'seqNum="(\d+)"', line).group(1)
        if seq in log_dict:
            print(log_dict[seq], line)
```

Comment: thank you, that worked as you stated, but how would i now split the line to just get the date out of both files

Comment: sorry i now think i should have added that at the beginning

Comment: Use a regular expression, similar to the way I pulled out the sequence number.